# Solving differential equation to series solution

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion

I tried to solve y''+x^2y=0 this differential equation to the series solution, so I put the command of AsymptoticDSolveValue[y''[x]+x^2*y[x]==0, y[x], {x,0,5}] like this, but the output shows like this in the photo.
[image]
However, I want to make the result of the general solution look like this. y = C1(1 - (1/12)x^4 + (1/672) x^8 - ...) + C2(x - (1/20)x^5 + (1/1440) x^9 - ...)

Could you please type the command on how to solve the general series solution for the differential equation?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. If I understand correctly, you just have to tell Mathematica to give you more terms, for example: ``AsymptoticDSolveValue[y''[x] + x^2*y[x] == 0, y[x], {x, 0, 15}]``

Comment: It seems it is working! However, for AsymptoticDSolveValue[2x*y''[x] -(3+2x)*y[x] +1 == 0, y[x], {x, 0, 5}], this differential equation command, I think it is not properly outputting the solution because the solution should be like y=C1(1+(1/3)x-(1/6)x^2-(1/6)x^3+...)+ C2 x^(5/2) (1+(4/7)x + (4/21)x^2+...) like this but the output from mathematical is different